Enable Search feature in PDF in Android app
I am working on a feature to enable search functionality in an in-app pdf viewer in android. We want to restrict opening the pdf in external apps because user should not be able to download the document. Currently, the in-app pdf viewer uses pdfRenderer to show the pdf. Please suggest if someone has any inputs in order to implement this. Any libraries or tools which are not open source would work
I tried controlling the download of document in external app via flags in intent but that is not working

You only have to wait for a bit... https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/features#pdf

I've not used this myself but there is a port of Apache PDFBox at https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android
You could extract text from the PDF and the search the extracted text. It also can render the PDF to an image which you can then display in the App instead of using pdfRenderer
